# why does the function $f(x)=x(\sqrt[x]{x+1}-1) $ behaves like it has infinte many extremums?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, maxima-minima

I was playing with graphing calculator and I was playing with $f(x)=x(\sqrt[x]{x+1}-1) $ to see will it reach infinity ,but to my surprise the function behaves very weird at the large numbers
I am not sure if this is because large numbers makes some eror in the calculator or it because it has  infinitely many extremums
[image]

one way to answer this question is to find the derivative of this function and make it equal to zero and then solve for $x$ but the problem is I can't solve $\sqrt[x]{x+1}+x(\sqrt[x]{x+1})(\frac{1}{(x)(x+1)}-\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2})=1$

also the calculator go as far as denoting the points which the function has minima or maxima point , this make me believe it is not an eror [image]

Comment: what value of $n$ is used for the graph?

Comment: sorry it is x not n @univalence

Comment: Considering the large numbers you're looking at, the issue is almost certainly tied to rounding errors. Especially considering $f$ is monotone increasing.

Comment: $x(e^{\ln(x+1)/x}-1)=x(\ln(x+1)/x+O(\ln(x)^2/x^2))$ $=\ln(x+1)+O(\ln(x)^2/x)$, so for large $x$, you basically have $\ln$.

Comment: This is just an artefact of limited-precision floating-point rounding errors. Nothing to see here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer: You're being bitten by floating-point rounding error.**

Long answer: First, let's rewrite the xth root (which typically isn't a standard function in computer math libraries) in terms of the more common natural logarithm and exponential.

$$f(x)=x(\exp(\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x})-1)$$

Let's break this down step-by-step, introducing temporary variables as needed.

$$t_1 := x + 1$$
$$t_2 := \ln(t_1)$$
$$t_3 := t_2 / x$$
$$t_4 := \exp(t_3)$$
$$t_5 := t_4 - 1$$
$$f(x) := x \times t_5$$

Let's plug in a concrete large value of $x$.  For example, $x = 10^{6}$ (aka a million).  Doing the arithmetic in [standard double-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) gives:

$$t_1 := 1000001$$
$$t_2 := 13.815511557963774$$
$$t_3 := 1.3815511557963774 \times 10^{-5}$$
$$t_4 := 1.0000138156069927$$
$$t_5 := 1.3815606992650942 \times 10^{-5}$$
$$f(x) := 13.815606992650942$$

So far, so good.  If you evaluate the expression to high precision [in WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=10%5E6+*+%28%2810%5E6+%2B+1%29%5E%2810%5E-6%29+-+1%29), and *then* round to the nearest `double`, you get $13.81560699258307$.  The error is a mere 4.9 parts per trillion.

But suppose that you didn't have access to the full 53 bits (≈15.95 decimal digits), and had to round all of the intermediate results to only 7 significant digits.

$$t_1 := 1000001$$
$$t_2 := 13.81551$$
$$t_3 := 1.381551 \times 10^{-5}$$
$$t_4 := 1.000014$$
$$t_5 := 1.4 \times 10^{-5}$$
$$f(x) := 14$$

We do *not* get the correctly-rounded result of $13.81561$, but instead only the two significant digits of $14$ — an error of 1.33%.

Taking a close look at the numbers, we see that the error is mostly introduced at the step $t_5 := t_4 - 1$.  We're taking a number that's *slighty* greater than 1, and subtracting 1 from it.  This is an example of what's called [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation).

Answer (score 1):

Most mathematical software can't handle big numbers correctly. Even advanced software could need some tweaking. Here's the graph in Mathematica with the default parameters:

[image]

and here's the graph after I asked it to use more precision:

[image]